# Getting metadata error while trying to save values to DB using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, crud

I am little new to entity framework.

I created a sample applicaiton to save values to the DB table using entity framework.

I have given below my code snippet.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Employee(EmployeeModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // insert
                var _insert = new EmployeeModel
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    Initial = model.Initial,
                    DOB = model.DOB,
                    DOJ = model.DOJ,
                    Role = model.Role,
                    City = model.City,
                    State = model.State,
                    Country = model.Country
                };
                db.Employee_Master.AddObject(_insert);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View();
            }
```

I am getting the below compilation error in "db.Employee_Master.AddObject(_insert);" line.

> "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet.AddObject(FinancialManagementSystem.Models.Employee_Master)' has some invalid arguments S:\SourceCode\FinancialManagementSystem\FinancialManagementSystem\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Add instead AddObject.
EmployeeModel is model to transfer data between View and Controller.
Which is the table where you want to insert into?
Take example, you have table Employee.

```
public DbSet<Blog> Employees { get; set; } 

db.Employees.Add(new Employee {FirstName = model.FirstName,....});
```

But if you still want to use AddObject:

```
db.Employee_Master.AddObject(new Employee {...}); //Employee is the name of the class represent for Employee_Master, maybe is Employee_Master of your problem.
```

Here is the different between Add and AddObject: http://blog.cincura.net/232485-someentityset-addobject-vs-addtosomeentityset-methods/